# Are deleted comments lost forever?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I can't see a way to view comment history, unlike edit history for a question itself. Can this be done? Does it require a high reputation?

Comment: There is no edit history for a comment, You can only view if the comment was edited or not. Also if a comment is deleted than we USERs can't view it. But I guess the moderators can view it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deleted comments are not gone forever, but seeing them requires moderator access.

Comment: It is moderator access only (and I didn't vote on your post. :-))

Comment: Thanks, when do you get moderator access? Is this part of usual progression?

Comment: @NickCardoso: There are [moderator elections](http://stackoverflow.com/election/). Moderators are chosen by the community.

Comment: @NickCardoso No; mods are elected by the community. They are typically very well-known and respected users (and generally therefore have very high reputation).

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! I asked because somebody I was trying to help started arguing and deleted the comments. It's needless really but I would like to have been able to double check I was right!

Comment: Also worth to mention diamond moderators (which by the way can also be SE employees) can undelete comments. :)

Comment: @NickCardoso - Yeah, that argument is exactly why we don't expose deleted comments (or their history) to even high-reputation users. I think it was for the best that both parties walked away from that one. Also, the other user didn't delete the comments, a moderator did in response to several flags there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Brad, although it's still frustrating